# primefaces barChart costum x-axes

Tags: java, xhtml, primefaces, integer

I have p:barchart graph in my application similar to the second barchart on the showCase:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/barChart.jsf

```
<p:barChart id="horizontal" value="#{chartBean.categoryModel}" legendPosition="se" style="height:300px"  
            title="Horizontal Bar Chart" orientation="horizontal" min="0" max="200"/>
```

how can I customize the Numbers on my X-axis. I want to format the x-axis to use only Integers.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this **(not tested)**:

```
<p:barChart extender="ext" id="horizontal" value="#{chartBean.categoryModel}" legendPosition="se" style="height:300px"  
    title="Horizontal Bar Chart" orientation="horizontal"/>
```

In you js add this

```
function ext() {
   this.cfg.seriesDefaults = { 
       useSeriesColor: true, 
       min: 0, 
       max: 200, 
       tickInterval: 20, 
       tickOptions: { 
           formatString: '%d' 
       } 
   };
}
```

or this x axis only :

```
function ext() {
   this.cfg.axes = {
       xaxis:
       {
           tickInterval: 20,
           tickOptions: { 
               formatString: '%d' 
           } 
       }
   };
}
```

You can try playing with  `tickInterval`...

---

Straight from the [PrimeFaces Userguide](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html)

**Extender**

Charts provide high level access to commonly used jqplot options however there are many more
customization options available in jqplot. Extender feature provide access to low level apis to do
advanced customization by enhancing this.cfg object, here is an example to increase shadow depth
of the line series;

```
<p:lineChart value="#{bean.model}" extender="ext" />


function ext() {
    //this = chart widget instance
    //this.cfg = options
    this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
        shadowDepth: 5
    };
}
```

Refer to jqPlot docs for the documentation of available options;
http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html
Converter

Comment: @akoskm Yep...  Added for x axis... (again its not tested...)

Comment: thank you Daniel. It resolved my problem.
but from where did u get this? I did not found any documentations about cfg or the extender functions

Comment: @slowessam , which one worked for you ? posted some info about the extender , also, If your question was answered , you should accept my answer.

Comment: the second one worked. the this.cfg.axes. But just as @akoskm said, it formated both axes not just x.

Answer (score 2):

your extender function could be like this

```
    function customExtender() {
        this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickOptions = {
            formatString : '%d'
        };
        this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickInterval = 1;
    }
```

I had the same problem and this works great, I based on Daniel's Answer and some other code. This way it just format the desired axis, not both.

Answer (score 1):

In you js add this

```
function ext() {
    this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickOptions.formatString = '%d';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set format to axis from your @ManagedBean class using the following code:

```
Axis xAxis = categoryModel.getAxis(AxisType.X);
xAxis.setTickFormat("%.0f");
```

Comment: Working perfectly for me with Primefaces 6.0, thanks.
This is the answer I prefer since the tick format can be configured while creating the model in the Java code - no Javascript required.