# get integer number in absices in lineChart primefaces

Tags: primefaces, integer, linechart

I use this chart :

```
<p:lineChart id="linear" value="#{statistiquesMB.linearModel}" legendPosition="e"  
                title="Linear Chart"  minY="0" maxY="10" minX="1" maxX="12"  />
```

and I have the absices like that : [image]

I want to have all months 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

I don't find any attribute that allow what I want

Comment: You'll need to use an extender. See [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544626/primefaces-barchart-costum-x-axes

Comment: thank you : function ext() {
    this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickOptions.formatString = '%d';
}